# Concatenating 3 different strings and then storing the resulting string in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

So like my question says, I'm trying to get three strings into a single one, separated by a " ' " between them and then storing that resulting string into a different column (more than one case, so maybe I also need a loop?)

Here's what I have:

```
select 'insertGeneric(''' ||b.DESCRIPTION, b.name, get_json_v(a.value, 'svgName') SYMBOL from cat_entity b 
left join CAT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE a on b.id = a.id_cat_entity and a.NAME = 'styleOsp'
where b.name like 'LOC.PHYSICAL.IP.%';


insertGeneric('Cabinet', 'LOC.PHYSICAL.IP.236','CABINETA');
```

Trying to get those together, the third one is also removes the ".svg" from the string and basicly then storing them where I find the subtring 'LOC.PHYSICAL.IP.%'.

get_json_v is a function from my project, gives me string with name of the file.
I tried using a CONCAT() function but couldn't get it to work.
A friend suggested I did the concatenation with excell and then import , but I have no idea on how I would do that, so I prefer
with SQL.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I follow all of your question, but you can concatenate all the values and single quotes using the concaenation operator you are aldready using:

```
select 'insertGeneric(''' ||b.DESCRIPTION ||''','''|| b.name ||''','''||
  get_json_v(a.value, 'svgName') || ''')' SYMBOL 
from cat_entity b 
left join CAT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE a on b.id = a.id_cat_entity and a.NAME = 'styleOsp'
where b.name like 'LOC.PHYSICAL.IP.%';
```

So where you were separating the columns with a comma, you instead seperate the values with `||''','''||`.

You might find it slightly clearer broken down a bit:

```
select 'insertGeneric('
  || '''' || b.DESCRIPTION || ''''
  || ','
  || '''' || b.name || ''''
  || ','
  || '''' || get_json_v(a.value, 'svgName') || ''''
  || ')'
  as SYMBOL
from cat_entity b 
left join CAT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE a
on b.id = a.id_cat_entity and a.NAME = 'styleOsp'
where b.name like 'LOC.PHYSICAL.IP.%';
```

That will gove you a string holding a statement as you've shown, but it isn't clear what you will do with it - perhaps you are building up ananonymous block of statements to run dynamically.

Comment: Actually to be more precise , I'll be filling a column with all the generated strings...so I'll need to do an update right?